# mkvirtualenv is not working after deleting python2.7

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

After I have deleted python2.7 from my laptop I started getting this error.
I am trying to create virtual environment with [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)  `mkvirtualenv` using `/bin/easy_install`.
I have try this command

```
╭─ fsadykov ~
╰─() mkvirtualenv --python=`which python` example
```

and this one

```
╭─ fsadykov ~
╰─()  mkvirtualenv  example                                                                                                                                              1 ↵
New python executable in /Users/fsadykov/virtualenvs/example/bin/python
Please make sure you remove any previous custom paths from your /Users/fsadykov/.pydistutils.cfg file.
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...

  Complete output from command /Users/fsadykov/virt...s/example/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel:
  DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Looking in links: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/51/f45cea425fd5cb0b0380f5b0f048ebc1da5b417e48d304838c02d6288a1e/setuptools-41.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/ca/94d32a6516ed197a491d17d46595ce58a83cbb2fca280414e57cd86b84dc/pip-19.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/10/44230dd6bf3563b8f227dbf344c908d412ad2ff48066476672f3a72e174e/wheel-0.33.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip, wheel
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/bin/easy_install'

----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 810, in main
    symlink=options.symlink,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1105, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs, download=download)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 952, in install_wheel
    _install_wheel_with_search_dir(download, project_names, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1042, in _install_wheel_with_search_dir
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=script)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 903, in call_subprocess
    raise OSError("Command {} failed with error code {}".format(cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/fsadykov/virt...s/example/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

### Version

Virtualenvwrapper Version

```
╭─ fsadykov ~
╰─() mkvirtualenv --version                                                              
16.4.0
```

Python Version

```
╭─ fsadykov ~
╰─() python --version
Python 3.7.4
```

I want to delete python2.7 from my MacBookPro if it's posible and use for everything python3.7. But for some reason I am getting this error.

note: This file does not exist `/bin/easy_install`

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/bin/easy_install'
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with virtualenvwrapper but from the logging it seems that Python 2.x is still being used. Also, did you notice the warning in the logging: `Please make sure you remove any previous custom paths from your /Users/fsadykov/.pydistutils.cfg file.` I'm not sure what the purpose of this file is, but it might contain a path to your Python 2.x installation?? The permission error is likely because you need root access (`sudo`) to write in `/bin`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have tried with `sudo` still facing that error.

`sudo pip install flask
Collecting flask
  Downloading 
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask) (0.24)
Installing collected packages: Jinja2, Werkzeug, flask
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/bin/flask'`

Answer (score 0):

Hi here i can only give you suggestion. You should reinstall Python and try again it seems like there are some files missing. And then update both python and pip to the latest version.